# Android App Crashes on loading SKMaps with prebundled data

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I'm getting following Error in logcat (Only 1 line) and app crashes. I'm using preinstalled maps and able to successfully dump into the internal storage.

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 2690
>   (GLThread 658)

Comment: For this kind of issues you will need to send your project or SKMaps.zip file to dev@telenav.com so that they can investigate